# Bounding the projective dimension of modules by the number of points and arrows

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A=KQ/I$ be a finite dimensional connected quiver algebra with admissible ideal $I$ with n points and m arrows and $M$ an $A$-module.

> Question: Is the projective dimension of $M$ bounded by $n+m$ if it is finite?

Of course it would be surprising to see a proof, but maybe there is a simple counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good strategy to find examples that break this bound is to use Xi's construction of the *dual extension algebra*, which keeps the number of vertices, doubles the number of arrows, and exactly doubles the global dimension:

*Xi, Changchang*, [**Global dimensions of dual extension algebras**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02567802), Manuscr. Math. 88, No. 1, 25-31 (1995). [ZBL0851.16003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0851.16003).

For instance if the quiver is an oriented cycle ($n=m$), then the maximal finite global dimension that can be attained is $2n-2$, see

*Gustafson, William H.*, [**Global dimension in serial rings**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(85)90069-9), J. Algebra 97, 14-16 (1985). [ZBL0571.16011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0571.16011).

Since $\mathrm{gldim} (A)=2n -2 < 2n=n_A+m_A$, such an algebra $A$ with maximal finite global dimension is not itself a counterexample. But for its dual extension algebra $D$, we get $\mathrm{gldim} (D)=4n -4$ and $n_D+m_D=n + 2n = 3n$. So for $n \geq 5$, $$\mathrm{gldim} (D) >n_D+m_D,$$ and the bound does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample is the algebra $k\langle x,y| xyxy^2, xy^2xy^3, \dots ,xy^{k-1} xy^{k}\rangle $. It is connected ($n=1$) with  $m=2$ generators  and have global dimension $k$. So, the trivial module $M=k$ has projective dimension $k$.

Still, it seems unknown whether there exists a counterample among quadratic connected algebras.

Comment: With quiver algebra I meant a finite dimensional algebra. I made this more precise in the question. Your algebra seems to be not finite dimensional.